# How to unit test a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

Just a quick question... I currently have the following jQuery code with a selector in it.

```
var ID = "idControl"
function doesTreeViewExist()
{
    if($('#' + ID).length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I was wondering how do I write the test to test the selector using QUnit?  More specifically, I'm having trouble coming up with the syntax/code.

EDIT:

Ok, suppose now I want to mock the selector call instead because I cannot get access to the actual website.  I'm using JsTestDriver as my testing tool, which means I cannot touch the browser the tests are running in (else the test runs will stop).  What about in such situation?  How can I possibly test the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Jack and successfully mocked the jquery call and returned a custom length and expected result.

Something like:

```
jack (function() {
    jack.expect("$").exactly("1").withArguments("#" + ID).returnValue( {length:0} );
    doesTreeViewExist()
    assertEquals(false, result);
});
```

I have also managed to supply a DOM structure to satisfy the jquery call, as I'm using one of JsTestDriver's built-in function HtmlDoc.  Something like:

```
/*:DOC += <span id="idControl"></span> */
```

or simply create a DOM sturcture without the specified id to get the false statement.

HTH.

Answer (score 9):

The function you post, can be heavily simplified:

```
var ID = "idControl";
function doesTreeViewExist() {
  return !!$('#' + ID).length;
}
```

Using the `!!` construct (*double bitwise NOT*), to convert the `length` property to Boolean, it will return `false` only when length is zero.

Speaking about qUnit, you can easily setup a simple test like this:

```
test("Your selector test", function() {
  ok($('#idControl').length > 0, "idControl exists");
  // or simply
  ok($('#idControl').length, "idControl exists");
});
```

The `ok` function does a *boolean assertion*, equivalent to JUnit's assertTrue.

Answer (score 4):

I test selectors manually, then pass them to code that uses them.  I can then unit test the code that uses them.  If you want to just test a selector, you need access to the HTML it affects.  Your test could include HTML to target, something like:

```
test("selector works", function() {
    var html = $('<input type="select"><option value=0/></input');

    var result = $('option', html);

    ok(result.count() == 1);
});
```

But I don't do that...  I put my selectors at the edge of the code so I can get to them quickly and step through them under the debugger.  I'll have a simple class whose properties are those selectors.  Then I'll mock/stub that simple class, so I can write code for everything dependent on those selectors.
  The reason I don't test my selectors is because the HTML they target is generated by ASP.NET code, and hard to get to from a javascript test.  But I can wrap them in a Humble Object ("http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble Object.html") then test code that depends on that humble object.  Here's a simple wrapper class that I can replace with test doubles:

```
var createSelectWidget = function(rootSelector)
{
    return {
        userText : $('span', rootSelector),
        inputList : $('option', rootSelector),
    };
}
```

Whatever dependency injection pattern you use, you can then stub it like below.  Suppose my widget has a select input to read the value of, and a span I want to write some results to:

```
var createSelectWidgetStub = function()
{
    return {
        userText : { text = function() {}},
        inputList : { val = function() {}},
    };
}
```

I can then pass around this stub in tests where I want to isolate the dependency but don't care about interactions with that dependency.  When I want to verify interactions with the dependency, I can mock it with JSMock.  Suppose I want to verify interactions with the input list, I would prepare a stub with the one element mock'd:

```
var selectMock = createSelectWidgetStub();
selectMock.inputList = mc.createMock(selectMock.inputList);
```

Comment: `<input type="select" />` is not valid, you should use a `<select>` element, also on your first example `count()` is not defined, I think you want to use `size()` but I would recommend you to simply use the `length` property.

Comment: This is a nice idea.  But it sounds like something that a framework would handle it for me instead of me doing it manually.  But if the use of other framework is not allowed, this would definitely be an approach.

Comment: CMS- yeah I was just hypothesizing some HTML.  That wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: BeraCim- If you find a framework that helps this along let me know.  I use the QUnit test framework and the JSMock library, so I am using existing tools where available.